# Prestashop create module for multistore

Tags: prestashop

I want to create a module in prestashop which will be compatible in multisite. So can someone tell me how to make a module which will be compatible in multistore. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just follow [the official guidelines for creating a module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module), your module **will be** multistore.

Basically, in your code, if you use the Configuration class (Configuration::updateValue() for example), your changes will be applied for the current store. If you want to make changes for all the stores, you will have to you set/get the context, for example :

```
if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
  Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
```

The page "[Using the context object](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+Context+Object)" is really usefull too if you plan on writing template files.